# Mongoose query always returns null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The problem I have is that a Mongoose query always returns null.
I include the definition of the Schema and the query part.Im trying to query the User collection on Mongoose.Im also using the passport api for authentication.

```
var Schema=mongose.Schema;
  var UserSchema= new Schema
  (      {
    email :{type:String,unique:true,lowercase:true},
    password : String,
    profile :
    { name :{type :String, default : ''}, picture  :{type :String, default : ''} }, adress:String,
     history : [{date : Date , paid :{ type :Number,default :0}}]
   });

module.exports=mongose.model('User',UserSchema,'');

var passport=require('passport');
var LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User=require('../models/user');
/*Se llama con cada Post*/
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done)
{
  done(null,user_id);
});

/*Se llama con cada Get*/
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done)
{
  User.findById(id,function(err,user)
{
  done(err,user);
});
});

/*This is where I get the error*/
passport.use('local-login',
new LocalStrategy({
usernameField :'email',
passwordField : 'password',
passReqToCallback : true
},function (req,email,password,done) {
User.findOne({email:email},function(err,user){

if(err) return done(err);

if(!user){
  done(null,false);
}

if (!user.comparePassword(password)) {

  done(null,false);

}
return done(null,user);
})
}));
```

Comment: Your `findOne` callback parameter is `users` but it looks like you're trying to refer to it as `user`.